# using htaccess to redirect to a different domain and path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Trying to 301 redirect blog posts from blog.url.com to url.com/blog/*. In addition to redirecting, the paths of the individual posts have changed, as well, so I can't use a global rewrite rule.

I thought I knew how to do this, but I'm not getting the expected result. Here's an example:

`redirect 301 /post/1234/post-name   https://url.com/blog/post-name`

But when I visit `url.com/post/1234/post-name`, I end up being redirected to `https://url.com/blogpost/1234/post-name`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it had to do with another line in my htaccess, to redirect the root subdomain:

`redirect 301 /`

This was acting as a catch-all and messing up the individual redirects. Once I changed the root redirect to `redirect 301 /index.html`, which was where the directory index lived, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score -1):

```
#301 Redirects for .htaccess

#Redirect a single page:
Redirect 301 /pagename.php http://www.domain.com/pagename.html

#Redirect an entire site:
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/

#Redirect an entire site to a sub folder
Redirect 301 / domain name/subfolder/
```

Comment: That's what I've got, but doesn't work as expected. It's combining the new domain with the old slug.